# Could not cast value of type 'Swift._ContiguousArrayStorage<AppName.JobsNearBy>' (0x113b1a200) to 'AppName.JobsNearBy' (0x10e6e7e60)

Tags: ios, swift, web, paging

I'm trying to fetch data from web and trying paging using AZTableView library. I'm facing the above error. Here's my code

**My Modal class**

```
class JobsNearBy: NSObject {
var jobId: Int?
var title: String?
var companyName: String? }
```

**Fetch data code**
I fetch 10 rows from the web first time put them in object and append on array and return.

```
func jobsNearByFetch(pageNumber: Int, success:@escaping (_ status:Bool, _ jobsNearByArray:Any) -> (), failure:@escaping (_ message: Error) -> ()) {
let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Accept": "application/json",
                            "Authorization": "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhb"]
let url = "http://thedemo.net/demo/stdinaus/api/jobs-near-me?page=\(pageNumber)&latitude=27.6947033&longitude=85.3310636"
Alamofire.request(url, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    guard let jobsResponse = response.result.value as? [String:Any] else{
        print("Error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
        failure((response.result.error! as Error))
        return
    }
    //            print("response: \(jobsResponse)")
    let jobsNearByObj:JobsNearBy = JobsNearBy()
    var jobsNearByArray:Array = [JobsNearBy]()

    let dict = jobsResponse as NSDictionary
    let status = dict["status"] as? Int
    let meta = dict["meta"] as! NSDictionary
    let lastPage = meta["last_page"] as? Int

    let dataArray = dict["data"] as! NSArray
    for dataDict in dataArray{
        let dataCompanyName = dataDict as! NSDictionary
        let jobId = dataDict as! NSDictionary
        let title = dataDict as! NSDictionary
        if let companyName = dataCompanyName["company_name"],
            let jobId = jobId["jobId"],
            let title = title["title"]{
            jobsNearByObj.companyName = companyName as? String
            jobsNearByObj.jobId = jobId as? Int
            jobsNearByObj.title = title as? String
            jobsNearByArray.append(jobsNearByObj)
        }
    }
    success(true, jobsNearByArray)
}
```

}

**Code in AZTableViewController**

```
override func fetchData() {
    super.fetchData()
    if Util.isConnectedToInternet(){
        self.showLoading(view: self.view, text: "Loading..")
        APIHandler.sharedInstance.jobsNearByFetch(pageNumber: 1, success: { (status, jobsArray) in
            self.stopLoading(fromView: self.view)
            self.arrayOfJobs.removeAll()
            self.arrayOfJobs.append(jobsArray as! JobsNearBy)
            self.didfetchData(resultCount: self.arrayOfJobs.count, haveMoreData: true)
        }) { (failure) in
            self.stopLoading(fromView: self.view)
            print("Failure")
        }
    }else{
        Util.showAlert(title:"Oops", message:"No internet connection..", view:self)
    }

}

override func fetchNextData() {
    super.fetchNextData()
    if Util.isConnectedToInternet(){
        self.showLoading(view: self.view, text: "Loading..")
        APIHandler.sharedInstance.jobsNearByFetch(pageNumber: 2, success: { (status, jobsArray) in
            self.stopLoading(fromView: self.view)
            self.arrayOfJobs.append(jobsArray as! JobsNearBy)
            if self.arrayOfJobs.count < 10{
                self.didfetchData(resultCount: self.arrayOfJobs.count, haveMoreData: true)
            }else{
                self.didfetchData(resultCount: self.arrayOfJobs.count, haveMoreData: false)
            }
        }) { (failure) in
            self.stopLoading(fromView: self.view)
            print("Failure")
        }
    }else{
        Util.showAlert(title:"Oops", message:"No internet connection..", view:self)
    }
}
```

**I think I've made mistake on append line but unable to solve this. Please someone help me with the above error.**

Comment: what is the type of `jobsArray`?

Comment: var arrayOfJobs = [JobsNearBy]()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your completion handler for `jobsNearByFetch` returns an array of `JobsNearBy`, which you put into `jobsArray`

Then, you have a force cast of `jobsArray` to `JobsNearBy`, but it is an array, not a single instance of the object so the downcast fails and because it is a forced downcast your app crashes.

You *could* fix it by using `as! [JobsNearBy]`, but it is better to change the signature of the completion closure to indicate that it returns `[JobsNearBy]` instead of `Any`; then you don't need to downcast anything:

You shouldn't use `Any` when you can determine what the actual type is.  Also, you shouldn't use `NSDictionary` when working in Swift if you can avoid it.  Also, avoid force downcasting and unwrapping whenever possible.

Stylistically the boolean `success` parameter and a separate failure closure is a bit odd too; you would typically have a single closure that returns an optional `Error` - If error is `nil` then the operation was successful. 
I would have:

func jobsNearByFetch(pageNumber: Int, completion:@escaping ( _ jobsNearByArray:[JobsNearBy]?, error:Error?) -> ()) {

This way you can use a single trailing closure.

You also need to look at your `jobsNearByFetch` as there are some return paths that don't call a closure.

Finally, you should look at the [`Codeble`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) protocol as it can eliminate the JSON parsing code altogether.